# Getting id of associated child records in factory_boy

Tags: django, python-3.x, factory-boy, associated-object

I have a `function` with a number of `parameters`, then a specialized `instantiation` of that function, with some `settings` for each of the function's parameters. So I have a structure like the following:

```
class Function(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class FunctionParameter(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)

class FunctionInstantiation(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)

class ParameterSetting(models.Model):
    function_instantiation = models.ForeignKey(FunctionInstantiation)
    function_parameter = models.ForeignKey(FunctionParameter)
```

In `FunctionFactory` I can use `factory.RelatedFactory` to create the `parameters`.

But in `FunctionInstantiationFactory` I can't use `factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSetting)` to create `ParameterSettings`, because I don't have access to the `parameter` objects created within `FunctionFactory`, so I can't set `parameter_setting.function_parameter_id`.

How can `FunctionInstantiationFactory` look up the `parameter_id` of parameters created in `FunctionFactory`? Can I get at them from the return value of `RelatedFactory(FunctionFactory)`? Or do I need to look at the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Xelnor's answer, but fixes the bug so that only one `function_instantiation` is created, rather than one for each `parameter`/`parameter_setting` pair.

```
class FunctionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Function
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Function %d" % n)


class FunctionParameterFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionParameter
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)


class FunctionInstantiationFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionInstantiation
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)


class ParameterSettingFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ParameterSetting

    function_instantiation = factory.SubFactory(FunctionInstantiationFactory)
    function_parameter = factory.SubFactory(FunctionParameterFactory,
        function=factory.SelfAttribute('..function_instantiation.function'))


class FunctionToParameterSettingsFactory(FunctionInstantiationFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionInstantiation

    # This overrides the function_instantiation created inside
    # ParameterSettingFactory, which then overrides the Function creation,
    # with the SelfAttribute('..function_instantiation.function') syntax.
    parameter_setting_1 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 
        'function_instantiation')
    parameter_setting_2 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 
        'function_instantiation')
```

The following demonstrates the solutions to a few other problems anyone using this pattern will probably encounter, such as overriding related objects' values, and links to other tables, themselves linked. It draws largely from techniques Xelnor introduced in his answer.

```
class FunctionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Function
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Function %d" % n)


class FunctionParameterFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionParameter
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Function %d" % n)
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)


class ParameterSettingFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ParameterSetting
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Function %d" % n)

    function_instantiation = factory.SubFactory(FunctionInstantiationFactory)
    function_parameter = factory.SubFactory(FunctionParameterFactory,
        function=factory.SelfAttribute('..function_instantiation.function'))


class DatasetAnd2ColumnsFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Function
    dataset = factory.SubFactory(DatasetFactory,
        name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Custom dataset %d" % n))
    column_1 = factory.SubFactory(ColumnFactory, dataset=dataset,
        name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Column 1 %d" % n))
    column_2 = factory.SubFactory(ColumnFactory, dataset=dataset,
        name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Column 2 %d" % n))


# I found it neater not to inherit in the end, due to needing quite a lot of
# additional complexity not included in my original question.
class FunctionToParameterSettingsFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionInstantiation

    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Custom instantiation name %d" % n)
    # You can call Sequence to pass values to SubFactories
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory, 
        name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Custom function %d" % n))

    parameter_setting_1 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 
        'function_instantiation',
        # Note the __ syntax for override values for nested objects:
        parameter__name='Parameter 1',
        name='Parameter Setting 1')
    # Possible to use Sequence here too, and makes looking at data easier
    parameter_setting_2 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 
        'function_instantiation',
        parameter__name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Param 1 for fn %d" % n),
        name=factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Param Setting 1 for fn %d" % n))
```

I now need to create a dataset with some columns of data, and join the parameter_setting records with those columns. To do so, this goes at the end of `FunctionToParameterSettingsFactory`:

```
@factory.post_generation
def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
         return

    dataset = DatasetAnd2ColumnsFactory()
    column_ids_by_name = 
        dict((column.name, column.id) for column in dataset.column_set.all())

    # self is the `FunctioInstantiation` Django object just created by the `FunctionToParameterSettingsFactory`
    for parameter_setting in self.parametersetting_set.all():
        if parameter_setting.name == 'age_in':
            parameter_setting.column_id = column_ids_by_name['Age']
            parameter_setting.save()
        elif parameter_setting.name == 'income_in':
            parameter_setting.column_id = column_ids_by_name['Income']
            parameter_setting.save()
```

This is admittedly a bit hacky. I tried passing `column=column_1` in the RelatedFactory calls, but that triggered creation of multiple datasets, each column linked to a different one. I tried all sorts of acrobatics with SelfAttribute and LazyAttribute, but you can't use either in a RelatedFactory call, and you can't create something with SubFactory(SelfAttribute()) and then pass it into RelatedFactory, as that breaks SelfAttribute (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33110180)).

In my real code I had several more models with a foreign key to dataset and it all tied up fine.

Comment: My edits were rejected, sorry @Xelnor, I tried to keep the answer credit with you.

Comment: There is a bug in the last code sample. `dataset` is repeatedly created so `column_1` and `column_2` get different datasets (both with the overridden `name` field). If I create a `column_3` with `dataset=factory.LazyAttribute(lambda col: col.factory_parent.dataset)`, it works fine. If I then add `column_3` to a `ParameterSettingFactory` call, I get `AttributeError: The parameter dataset is unknown.` and factory_boy finds only ParameterSettingFactory locals, and no factory_parent.

Comment: I've solved the above issue, [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33110180/edit), and updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `factory.SubFactory` is intended to *follow* a `ForeignKey`; if you want to use it the other way around, you should use a `RelatedFactory` instead.

For your example, I'd go with the following factories:

```
class FunctionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Function
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "Function %d" % n)


class FunctionParameterFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionParameter
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)


class FunctionInstantiationFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.FunctionInstantiation
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)


class ParameterSettingFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ParameterSetting
        exclude = ['function']

    # We'll need a FunctionFactory; this field is part of 'exclude',
    # thus available while building the factory but not passed to the
    # target Django model
    function = factory.SubFactory(FunctionFactory)

    # Use the function from our Factory for both
    # function_instantiation and function_parameter
    function_instantiation = factory.SubFactory(FunctionInstantiationFactory,
        function=factory.SelfAttribute('..function'))
    function_parameter = factory.SubFactory(FunctionParameterFactory,
        function=factory.SelfAttribute('..function'))
```

And you can add an extra factory, `FunctionWithParametersFactory`, that creates parameters along:

```
class FunctionWithParametersFactory(FunctionFactory):
    parameter1 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 'function')
    parameter2 = factory.RelatedFactory(ParameterSettingFactory, 'function')
```

Calling that factory will perform the following:

1. Create a Function object (through FunctionFactory)
2. Call ParameterSettingFactory, pointing it to the created Function object
3. Call ParameterSettingFactory a second time, still pointing it to the same Function object
4. Return that Function object.

Comment: Sorry, just seconds ago I updated my question with `RelatedFactory` instead of `SubFactory`, while you were typing. Was just reading up on `SelfAttribute` but was hopelessly stuck along the lines of `function.parameter[0].id`. Will take me a few minutes to understand your code so bear with me before I mark as the answer. Huge thanks, as you can tell I'm new to factory_boy and its ilk.

Comment: Some notes, self-evident to anyone familiar with factory_boy. The `factory.SelfAttribute('..` syntax tells the SubFactory (`FunctionInstantiationFactory`) to get the named object (`function`) from the calling factory (`ParameterSettingFactory`) scope. `exclude` stops factory_boy from trying to save `function` as a foreign key on the `ParameterSetting` object (which doesn't have that FK). `FunctionWithParametersFactory`, by inheriting from `FunctionFactory`, starts by creating `Function`, then uses `ParameterSettingFactory` to create the other three. Huge thanks @Xelnor this taught me a lot.

Comment: From [the docs](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#parents) I think `function=factory.LazyAttribute(lambda function_parameter: function_parameter.factory_parent.function)` would be an alternative (inferior) way of implementing the second `function=factory.SelfAttribute('..function')`. @Xelnor's solution is nicer and neater in every way, just noting a related discovery.