# Why does the naming of RelatedFactory variables in factory-boy affect when the factories are executed/instantiated?

Tags: python, django, naming, factory-boy

When I named my RelatedFactory variables `pv_something`, the factories wouldn't be run until after the `post_generation` method. When I renamed the variables to `param_val_something` they would be run before the `post_generation` method.

In the following code, `RelatedFactory` is not run until after `post_generation`, so `self.something_set.all()` is empty, and the line `t.something_else = 'abc'` is never executed.

```
class ThingFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing

    name = 'a thing'

    pv_something = factory.RelatedFactory(SomethingFactory, 'thing')

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        for t in self.something_set.all():
            t.something_else = 'abc'
```

In the following code, the only difference is renaming the variable `pv_something` to `param_val_something`. Now, `self.something_set.all()` is *not* empty, and the line `t.something_else = 'abc'` *is* executed.

```
class ThingFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Thing

    name = 'a thing'

    param_val_something = factory.RelatedFactory(SomethingFactory, 'thing')

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        for t in self.something_set.all():
            t.something_else = 'abc'
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3, Django 1.8.5, and factory-boy 2.5.2.

Midnight Friday night, this nearly sent me over the edge..

Comment: I briefly wondered if the issue was population of the `self.something_set` list, but `Something.objects.filter(thing_id=self.id)` also failed to retrieve the RelatedFactory records.

Comment: Ridiculous as it sounds I am 100% certain the naming was all that changed to fix it. Now, randomly, the RelatedFactory calls are being called after post-gen again, with the 'fixed' variable names. My lazy solution was to move the `factory.RelatedFactory(SomethingFactory, 'thing')` calls into the post-gen method as `pv_something = SomethingFactory(thing=self)`. The order of RelatedFactory and post-gen doesn't seem to be guaranteed - presumably a consequence of some lazy evaluation somewhere.